# Obtaining target platform properties like background color and font size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The iOS and Android targets of Xamarin.Forms are visually quite different. To work around this gap:

Does **Xamarin.Forms provides a class**, which has **getters for visual properties** of the current target platform:

- Background color
- Font color
- Font size of TableView TableIntent.Menu text
- Font size of Label view text
- ...

You get the point: Obtain a full description of visual target platform properties.

**Does the framework provide these values? Or do I have to compute them manually (and how)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Xamarin.Forms` does not expose those values. The only device specific information exposed is `Color.Accent`.

You can retrieve the information you need quite easily, and inject it in you `Xaamrin.Forms` project. XF provides a basic DI container: `DependencyService`